# How to make classes from a Scala jar library of mine accessible in Scala console and Scala scripts?

Tags: scala, classpath, read-eval-print-loop

I just wonder how can I extend Scala console and "script" runner with my own classes so that I can actually use my code by means of using the actual Scala language to communicate to it? Where am I to put my jars so that they can be seamlessly accessed from every Scala instance without ad-hoc configuration?

Answer (score 4):

If you just need to interact with your code you can add a `-classpath` to the commandline when starting the repl.

```
scala -classpath mycode.jar
```

If you need to do more than that, start browsing the repl source. You can download it from github at https://github.com/scala/scala

Answer (score 2):

I use [sbt](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki) to accomplish this. It can start the repl with project classes and dependencies on the classpath by using "console" action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CLASSPATH variable directly, e.g.:

```
CLASSPATH="/Users/opyate/.ivy2/cache/com.mongodb.casbah/casbah-core_2.9.1/jars/casbah-core_2.9.1-2.1.5-1.jar:/Users/opyate/.ivy2/cache/com.mongodb.casbah/casbah-commons_2.9.1/jars/casbah-commons_2.9.1-2.1.5-1.jar" scala
```